# How to close window with apsx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page in window. Now i want to close it from cs code:

```
 string result = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.returnValue = true;
                   window.close();
                 </script>";
 Response.Write(result);
```

It's work fine.
Now i want to save a file and then close a window. And my code from above not work. I get a save file dialog, save a fine, but my window not close.
What i should do in this case?

**SAVE FILE CODE**

```
                File.WriteAllBytes(docFileName, documentStream.ToArray());

            fi = new FileInfo(docFileName);
            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                byte[] buffer;
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(docFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
                    buffer = new byte[fileSize];
                    // Read file into buffer
                    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, fileSize);
                    fileStream.Close();


                    fi.Delete();

                }


                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.BufferOutput = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docFileName);
                Response.CacheControl = "public";
                // writes buffer to OutputStream
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Response.End();
```

Comment: Put save file code also.......

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit: i'd add file save code. Please look at it.

Comment: Code after `Response.End();` will not be executed

Comment: I tried to remove Response.End(). But my window still not close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close the window like that.

You can only close the windows that was created by the script.